# vercel import work in some file and not in another file, nextjs nodejs

Tags: node.js, import, export, package.json, vercel

error occur log:

```
13:24:54:83
2021-08-11T07:54:55.292Z    undefined   ERROR   (node:8) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-08-11T07:54:55.303Z    undefined   ERROR   /var/task/api/userLoginEmail.js:8
export default async function (req, res) {
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:169:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async getListener (/var/task/___vc/__launcher.js:33:11)
   RequestId: df65f579-7eb4-4d5b-8f43-ed01c4e5ecd1 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
   Runtime.ExitError
```

Even after adding type: module to package json it breaks for other file, but similar code pass through without logging any logs? how it could be how it as got hold for just this?

This is the starting code of other file, where it works without any error logs

````
   import Cookies from "cookies";
   import { createEmailTemplate } from "./functions";

   export default async function (req, res) {
    // Create a cookies instance
    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);

    // // Get a cookie
    // LINE BELOW COMMENTED FOR VERCEL DEPLOYMENT TEST!
    if (req.method !== "POST" && cookies.get("kAppToken") !== null && 
    process.env.API_ACCESS_SECRET_TOKEN) return res.status(403).send(res.send("not allowed"));```
````

Answer (score 0):

How about giving a name to your function ??

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {}
```

Comment: other file too doesn't have any name specified and it works, this kind of code is for serverless function in nextjs application use. I guess that is not the reason for the error, am I mistaking?

Comment: But did you try naming it ?

Comment: nope, naming doesn't make difference. I found after debugging the file on local, there was typo gotcha in the code which was causing to fail on vercel. after that no error on above.